# Which institutions will hold a real estate "trust deed"?

Tags: real-estate, trusts, investment-trusts

Pardon me if my question is stupid.
I was Googling what a Trust deed is and in one of the websites, there is the following phrase.

> A trust deed—also known as a deed of trust—is a document sometimes
> used in real estate transactions in the U.S. It is a document that
> comes into play when one party has taken out a loan from another party
> to purchase a property. The trust deed represents an agreement between
> the borrower and a lender to have the property held in trust by a
> neutral and independent third party until the loan is paid off.

In that passage, I would like to understand the part.

> The trust deed represents an agreement between the borrower and a
> lender to have the property held in trust by a neutral and independent
> third party until the loan is paid off.

Which type of institutions are the

> **neutral and independent third party**

Are they companies within the lenders themselves (Banks), government institutions or some type of corporation that deals with this type of business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The neutral and independent third-party is usually a title company or attorney, https://www.bankrate.com/mortgages/deed-of-trust/.